# Printing key in Vue.js iteration

Tags: vue.js

I have array like below

```
data() {
  return {
    shoppingItems: [
      {name: 'apple', price: '10'},
      {name: 'orange', price: '12'}
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to iterate like below

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in shoppingItems">
    {{ item.name }} - {{ item.price }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am getting output like below

- apple - 10
- orange - 12

But I would like to get output like below

- name - apple, price - 10       //I would like to print key dynamically
- name - orange, price - 12

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `(key,value)` pair in `for`  loop

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data() {
  return {
    shoppingItems: [
      {name: 'apple', price: '10'},
      {name: 'orange', price: '12'}
    ]
  }
}
});
```

```css
li span{
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in shoppingItems">
    <span v-for="(v,i,count) in item">{{i}} - {{v}}<span v-show="count<(Object.keys(item).length-1)
">, </span></span>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can iterate over the keys/values with [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object) :

```
<div v-for="(value, key) in object">
  {{ key }} - {{ value }}
</div>
```

You can also have the index of the current key :

```
<div v-for="(value, key, index) in object">
  {{ key }} - {{ value }}
  // if index > 0, add comma
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Thoomas. I assume your solution and I implement your solution. But it is not working. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Thoomas. If I use this code `<div v-for="(value, key) in object">
  {{ key }} - {{ value }}
</div>` nothing is printed for `{{key}}`. Thanks.

Comment: If you kept the same variable names', replace `object` with `item` and put this code inside your first loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use default way of Vue to do this

```
<div v-for="(value, name) in object">
  {{ name }}: {{ value }}
</div>
```

Easy and simple

Answer (score 0):

Object.Keys(Object) returns an array containing all the key of the object. Now you can use index to fetch the desire key -

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in shoppingItems">
    {{ Object.keys(item).indexOf(0) }} : {{ item.name }} - {{ Object.keys(item).indexOf(1) }} : {{ item.price }}
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes. I realized that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that we have a person array or list which contain person object                     `persons`:

```
[{name:'Suru', age:4, hairColor:'red'}, {name: 'Sofia', age:'5', hairColor:'green'}]
```

Now let's loop through person list and get **key, value, and index**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    persons: [
      {name: 'Suru', age: 4, hairColor: 'red'},
      {name: 'Sofia', age: '5', hairColor: 'green'}
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="person in persons">
      <span v-for="(value, key, index) in person">
        {{key}}: {{value}} - {{index}}<br>
      </span>
      <br>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```