# attribute name from array of objects as varible?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

everyone help Please, i have:

> ```
>   fields: [
>     { email: 'ignat@domain.com' },
>     { phone: '+1223456789' },
>     { address: 'Paris, some address..' }
>   ]
> ```

How can I get something like this?:

```
<div v-for="(field,index) in fields" :key="index">
<span> {{field.attributeName}}</span>
<span> {{ field.attributeValue }}</span>
</div>
```

I mean without enter attribute names manually (just get it from array)
Plz help Im newbie

> I just want to generate field for contact by user input, user press
> ADD button and gets 2 fields. First - key, second - value for this key,
> key and value user insert manually. Ive thought that i could avoid
> using 2 array method for this((

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you get stuck? Can you show the *exact* output you want to obtain after processing the `fields` Array? Please take a read of the "*[ask]*" guidelines, and consider taking the [tour].

Comment: After array processing i wanna get keys as values to show it in template.

Comment: You have a data problem, your data should be in an object instead of array format.

Comment: I just want to generate field for contact by user input, user press ADD button and gets 2 fields first - key, second - value for this key, key and value user insert mannualy. Ive thought that i could avoid using 2 array method for this((

Comment: Great, but you need to add that information - as well as the exact form of the desired result, in html - to the question. Comments are transitory, and may well be deleted. As I said above, look at the guidelines and then edit your question so you might get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure inside a for loop. So your v-for would look like this:

```
<div v-for="({email, phone, address},index) in fields" :key="index">
<span> {{ email }}</span>
<span> {{ phone }}</span>
<span> {{ address}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like the OP wants the name of the given key in one `<span>` and the value held by that Object key in the next; unless I'm misunderstanding something - and it's quite possible, I really aren't familiar with Vue - your answer will result in only the values being printed out?

Comment: Ah, well this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51055711/printing-key-in-vue-js-iteration

Comment: No, sorry but it isnt, case in this array could be many different attribute names for every person, and i need create variable from attribute name, to show it right, how could i do this? for example email: name@mail.com, and if first element of array could be birthday, than i need - birthday: 10.10.12

Answer (score 0):

Oh thanks for comments Ive understand, my fault

i need transform data to:

> ```
>   fields: [
>     { key: email, value: 'ignat@domain.com' },
>     { key: phone, value: '+1223456789' },
>     { key: address, value: 'Paris, some address..' }
>   ]
> ```

And Show it:

```
<div v-for="(field,index) in fields" :key="index">
<span> {{field.key}}</span>
<span> {{ field.value}}</span>
</div>
```

Thanks For Help!

Comment: As was mentioned in the comments to the question, you could also use destructuring to help: `v-for="({key,value},index) in fields"` [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yv8btckn/).